# How to create a bootable USB from a .iso file?

Tags: boot, usb-drive, iso

I am trying to create a bootable USB stick from a .iso image (it isn't a linux distro or anything of the sort) intended for use with a CD. I've tried `UNetbootin` and `dd` but they don't boot.

Comment: Could please be more specicif, what OS will be running from the ISO? the booting creating process depends on the OS which you want to boot from.

Comment: If you do this, your USB Stick will work for less time than usual. You can't write a USB stick many times. Cheers!

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/59551/how-to-burn-iso-to-usb-device/60430#60430

Comment: I created a bootable USB drive following this method https://youtu.be/wJRzndIgzL4

Answer (score 12):

Try Ubuntu Startup disk creator, I don't think it discriminates about which input ISO you give it.  (**System->Administration->Startup Disk Creator**), then select the .iso you want to burn and the output USB drive.  I've used it several times now for creating a boot environment on both a thumb drive and a backup USB hard drive.

You haven't told us anything about the USB drive itself though, it might be handy to::

- print the output of **sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdX** (where sdX is the device (sda/sdb/sdc etc) name given to the USB drive upon plugging it in, you can find this at the bottom of **dmesg** as you insert the drive)

  > ```
  > Mine (in a MacbookPro):
  > Device      Boot    Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
  > /dev/sdb1               1          26      204819+  ee  GPT
  > /dev/sdb2   *          26        3065    24414064   af  HFS / HFS+
  > /dev/sdb3            3082        3212     1048576   82  Linux swap / Solaris
  > /dev/sdb4            3212        9291    48827392   83  Linux
  > ```
  >
  > (Make sure a partition on the drive is actualy marked as bootable (* in the boot column)
- attempt to boot from a bootable USB thumb drive or similar on your machine to test it, maybe its not capable or not setup to boot from an external USB device (check BIOS for more info)
- also, try the bootable drive on another machine as this will at least tell you if the drive itself is working correctly

Comment: The USB creator ("usb-creator-gtk") won't touch an openSUSE .iso when I try it. It seems to only like Ubuntu .iso files.

Comment: This tool is no longer necessary for openSUSE as their ISO's have been designed to be bootable using only the dd command

Comment: Startup Disk Creator reliably crashes for me, both when I try 'Erase Disk', and when I try to create the USB image. Starting it using 'sudo usb-creator-gtk --allow-system-internal', as suggested on related SO threads, does not help. Ubuntu 15.04 Desktop.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution isn't generally useful and doesn't correctly answer the question asked; it will only write ubuntu distro iso, and can't be used to write other bootable isos (still as of 16.04!)

Answer (score 8):

Usually, Unetbootin works perfectly so try to file a bug if possible.

If you want to make a bootable ubuntu flash disk, you could try the Ubuntu Startup Disk Writer.

For Fedora, there is a similar utility.

Comment: Calixte said: "(it isn't a linux distro or anything of the sort)"...

Comment: Worked perfectly for me first time (for a bootable Ubuntu ISO), while other answers on this page could not be made to work.

Answer (score 0):

[MultiBoot USB](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/) does what you want.  Your ISO should be a Linux distribution though.

Comment: Asker said "it isn't a linux distro"

Answer (score 0):

A "bootable" USB disk requires a "bootable" ISO files to be burned on it.

The litmus test is simple: If burning the said ISO on a DVD would get you a bootable DVD, then any of the methods (like "startup disk creator") to "burn" the ISO on usb would do the trick. But if the ISO would not give you a bootable DVD, then it can **NEVER** give you a bootable USB, because bootable is just not what your ISO is.

I know I am reviving a two year old thread, but looking at the number of views, and its unanswered status, I could not resist answering it.

Answer (score 0):

The best software to create a bootable USB from a .iso file for me is  [multisystem](http://liveusb.info/dotclear/) which can be downloaded by clicking [this link](http://liveusb.info/multisystem/install-depot-multisystem.sh.tar.bz2).

[image: interface]

Comment: The website does not seem to have anything for download. Only selling USB sticks.

Comment: That picture looks like someone saw a widget toolkit demo and though "so this is what a UI is supposed to look like"