# Make Bootable USB disk for DBAN?

Tags: usb, iso

I am confused how to make it, found DBAN [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57037/how-to-make-data-recovery-very-very-hard-or-impossible-for-unix-computer-before). I have an empty USB -disk and DBAN.*.iso. How can I do it with Ubuntu?

---

I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/60430/62483) to create the bootable ISO for the DBAN. I downloaded the ISO [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dban/files/dban/dban-2.2.7/dban-2.2.7_i586.iso/download). Then I did

```
$ umount /dev/sdb1
$ sudo dd if=dban.iso of=/dev/sdb1
```

and booted my thinkpad and then booted from the USB: press the blue Thinpad -button, choose USB and then wait but here my computer does not do anything. Just black screen.

Something went wrong?!

Comment: You already have the image, now you must *burn* this one into the USB flash disk. If you want to know **how to make a USB bootable** with an `.ISO` file you should see this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/60430/62483

Answer (score 2):

I think the key is to use the drive `/dev/sdb`, not the partition `/dev/sdb1`, in the `of=` option:

```
sudo dd if=dban.iso of=/dev/sdb
```