# need help putting ubuntu on a usb it has 2g of free space

Tags: live-usb

need help putting ubuntu on a usb I dont see any options to download ubuntu onto a usb it just says desktop, server, or cloud dont know which one is for usb's help please thnks

Comment: Do you want to download Ubuntu and install it to the USB so you can run it from that USB, or do you want to download it and and create a bootable USB so you can use the USB to install Ubuntu to the hard drive of a computer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator)

Comment: Whoops that was the wrong one. Should be this instead: http://askubuntu.com/questions/59551/how-to-burn-iso-to-usb-device/60430#60430 We really have to much of these.

Answer (score 0):

Use Lilyusb at http://www.linuxliveusb.com/
you can read the instruction at there
for make usb linux key, just decide the OS you want.
If you want to make linux key running on Ubuntu 12.04...download its ISO