# Partition Magic USB Creation on Ubuntu

Tags: usb, live-usb

I want to create a [Partition Magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PartitionMagic) bootable USB, but I don't have the necessary software to do this.

I tried Startup Disk Creator but the program can't open the Partition Magic ISO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Startup Disk Creator is only designed to handle Debian-based ISOs. Partition Magic is proprietary as far as I know which is why it doesn't know what to do. Taken from the description:

> The program also works for Debian, or any other Debian-based OS for
>   which you have a CD or .iso image.

Instead you should look at more raw disk image "burning" options like UNetbootin or even `dd`:

- [How to burn a Windows .iso to a USB device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59551/how-to-burn-a-iso-to-a-usb-device)

---

And yes, question if you really need Partition Magic at all. It hasn't been updated since 2004.

The Ubuntu CD image has gParted on it which is just more powerful and supports more, newer partition types. And it's free.

Answer (score 1):

Use `gparted` instead. It's included in the Ubuntu live USB. Boot Ubuntu from USB, run `sudo gparted` in a prompt and you are on your way.