# How do I install Ubuntu from USB in debian?

Tags: boot, usb, system-installation, iso, debian

After looking through the Ubuntu instructions for creating a bootable USB I googled this and it seems like there's a plethora of different ways that one could do this. Here's what I've tried:

1. Download the `Ubuntu 14.04.1 desktop 64-bit` iso.
2. Find a [link explaining how to create a bootable ubuntu iso](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59551/how-to-burn-a-iso-to-a-usb-device).
3. run `dd if=path/to/iso of=/dev/sdd1` as per instructions.
4. Try to boot. Nothing (blinking cursor, no activity until I hit Ctrl+Alt+Del
5. Look for another link, this time telling me to install `unetbootin`
6. Try to boot, get a [Failed to load COM32 file menu.c32](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unetbootin/+bug/1190256). The suggested fix is to look for a file. Checked. Doesn't exist on my system.
7. Go and google again. This time I'm told [debian ISOs can be copied directly](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch04s03.html.en). Maybe Ubuntu isos can be copied in this way? Nope.
8. [Check instructions on Ubuntu website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) again. Instructions less than helpful.
9. Come here and ask.

Does anyone have a way of creating a bootable Ubuntu USB stick that works with Ubuntu 14.04 and can be used in a `Debian` system?

Comment: The menu.c32 error you got was a bug in your version of UNetbootin. Don't eve use the version in the repos. Instead, download the latest version from SourceForge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootable ISO images contain a partition table and boot record, and thus must be written to a *disk* rather than to a *partition*. The [`dd`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dd&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%207.0%20wheezy&format=html&locale=en) command you ran wrote the ISO image to `sdd1`, which is the first partition of the disk `sdd`. Write it just to `sdd` instead.

```
dd if=path/to/iso of=/dev/sdd
```

---

Of course, as [ubuntu_tr says](https://askubuntu.com/a/523474/22949), always check that `sdd` is actually the correct device, or you might overwrite and destroy data on a totally different drive. I've made this sort of mistake, and while my backups saved me, it was a considerable inconvenience! Remember that a removable device's device node entry can change between mounts. (And if there are other systems you administer, make sure you're not accidentally SSH'd into one of them and inadvertently running `dd` on it remotely.)

Ubuntu users--people using Ubuntu to write the Ubuntu (or other) ISO image to the flash drive--will need to run [`dd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dd.1.html) with [`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/sudo.8.html):

```
sudo dd if=path/to/iso of=/dev/sdd
```

On Debian (the OS that Arman's using to create Ubuntu installation media), `sudo` is one of multiple widely used and supported options, the main other being to [`su`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=su&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%207.0%20wheezy&format=html&locale=en) to root with a separate root password. In contrast, Ubuntu systems [almost always require `sudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) to run a command as root.

Comment: Right, I did not know that! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
dd if=Ubuntu\ 14.04.1\ desktop\ 64-bit.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=512k
```

sdb may change according to your system. Double check.

Comment: If the name of input file really has spaces in it, they will need to be  quoted. For example, `dd if='Ubuntu 14.04.1 desktop 64-bit.iso' of=/dev/sdb bs=512k` or `dd if=Ubuntu\ 14.04.1\ desktop\ 64-bit.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=512k`. (The default names of Ubuntu ISOs don't have spaces, though.)

Comment: You are right.I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is an error with either UNetbootin or Syslinux, imo.

Basically, Unetbootin installs this without 3 files whose functions are normally provided by Syslinux.

Try the following commands after doing a vanilla UNetbootin installation to a USB drive:

```
cd /usr/lib/syslinux/modules/bios/
cp libcom32.c32 /media/path/to/usb/drive/
cp libutil.c32 /media/path/to/usb/drive/
cp menu.c32 /media/path/to/usb/drive/
```

If you have any more questions about this, PM me.

I solved this using the instructions here: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/unetbootin/+bug/1190256

And here: 
https://bugs.mageia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11910

The Mageia guys are gs.