# Write Ubuntu iso image to USB

Tags: usb, debian, unetbootin

I am a new Linux user. I recently installed Debian stable 8 from Windows through unetbootin but now I would like to use Ubuntu. I have downloaded Ubuntu iso file. But I am not able to write it to USB as in Debian, I am unable to install unetbootin both from repository and direct download as nothing happens when I double click the unetbootin file even though it is marked executable. I tried various other command options, also searched on google but all solutions had some problems. Please advice me how to make my USB bootable with Ubuntu preferably with unetbootin.

Comment: don't know much about unetbootin but use rufus for windows instead or universal usb installer.  Rufus is better in my opinion but universal usb installer has more widespread compatibility.  (Source: Any google search with programs I mentions)

Comment: Did you have a look at this post here => http://askubuntu.com/questions/523472/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-usb-in-debian

Comment: This how-to site explains dd write to USB better... [How to Burn an ISO File to a USB Drive in Linux](https://www.howtogeek.com/414574/how-to-burn-an-iso-file-to-a-usb-drive-in-linux/)

Answer (score 2):

The preferred way to make a bootable usb in debian is using `dd`. so:

> `sudo dd if=/path_to/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/usb-mount-point`

will write the contents of ubuntu.iso file to `usb-mount-point`. You have to see where you have mounted the USB (you can use `sudo fdisk -l` to see (usually it will be `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/sdc`).

It is important to be absolutely sure of the mount point of usb before running the `dd` command.

Comment: You forgot to add a filename on the mounted directory e.g. `of=/dev/usb-mount-point/Ubuntu.iso`. I am not quite sure how `dd` handle a missing filename on the destination directory but I think it is clearer for all if a filename is stated. Cheers

Comment: @Mike you do not need to add a filename on mounted directory because we are writing the contents of .iso file to the mounted device directly.

Comment: It's not /dev/usb-mount-point but rather /dev/sd[letter] with "letter" being a single alphabet letter designating the USB drive. Try lsscsi tool (not installed by default) in order to identify the device.

Answer (score 2):

The one and only [supported way](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) to "burn" an ISO image to a USB drive (memory stick) is the "USB Creator" tool aka "Startup Disk Creator".

It basically does some conversion and then copies the stuff onto the USB device.
Be warned that the USB device content will be wiped as a result for the whole process!