# New User needs help removing root kit virus

Tags: networking, security, dns, malware

I clicked on a PUP pretending to be Norton and then subsequently installed Malware/Trojan. This virus overwrites the firmware of your router and redirects your DNS (doing a hardware reset does not recover your router - nasty). Once your DNS has been redirected you are taken to fake websites which capture your login details when attempting to login to various websites eg. email/security/financial/internet providers/telecom carriers, etc.

I want to use Ubuntu to create a bootable CD/DVD with current antivirus software and definitions to detect and remove the virus from Bios, HDD’s and OS. I don’t know much about Linux and would appreciate any help as to which antivirus and boot system to use. Looking for any help/advice.
Thanks, Peter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write Ubuntu iso image to USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629732/write-ubuntu-iso-image-to-usb)

Comment: Did you look up the Ubuntu tutorials ?  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview  Once written to media; you can boot it *live* on a system, install software as needed etc (including `clamav` etc)   FYI:  What you're hoping to do I suspect is beyond a new users capabilities; at least to do it safely..  If you can't work it out yourself, you're probably best seeking help or tech support,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a bootable Clonezilla USB that works?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477573/how-to-create-a-bootable-clonezilla-usb-that-works)

Comment: Sorry for your problem, do not forget you need to either revert back to an older version or update the firmware in your router. If you cannot then you will have to replace it.

Comment: Thanks Gil. Have used the reset button but it still boots to corrupted firmware. Haven’t tested by downloading and flashing new firmware yet, still trying to get a clean/trusted system to use for that. Will appreciate any further comments.