# Re installing using USB

Tags: uninstall, reinstall

on my recently bought HP desktop I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 using a USB. It worked like a dream for a few months until suddenly it could not connect with the internet, I have wireless in my house. I have tried a few suggestions but nothing changed. As I could use the computer with a window boot, I left it for some time, but now windows is showing its own problems and I want to get Ubuntu properly working.
How would I go about uninstalling and reinstalling Ubuntu using USB?

Comment: You don't uninstall an OS; you just install another OS, or the same OS over it.   I'm actually involved in QA testing (*Quality Assurance*), and I use the re-install process as a means to upgrade some existing installs I use for *support* purposes; ie. I perform a non-destructive re-install of the OS using a *daily* ISO which upgrades my packages; checks the install works & my *manually installed* packages get auto-reinstalled as part of the QA test procedure.  No uninstall is performed; you just install Ubuntu over an existing installation (*without format in my case*)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I am still stuck with the same situation, due to several attempts which all run into dead ends and to avoid frustration taking over used a borrowed laptop instead. Understand what you say about not Uninstaller but computer doesn't seem to recognize my USB Ubuntu file.

Comment: If the computer isn't recognizing the USB thumb-drive as bootable, chances are the issue is the ISO was incorrectly written to the thumb-drive...  How you boot external media varies on device; ie. I have a device which requires me to have the device powered off, then I hold  key down and 4 seconds later it will boot *inserted* external media.. If the device is already running, it won't boot any external media which was seen as a security feature in the *firmware*... ie. your issue maybe you incorrectly using your device too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write Ubuntu iso image to USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629732/write-ubuntu-iso-image-to-usb)

Comment: Official tutorials can be found here - https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview 
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-windows#1-overview
etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will “Erase Ubuntu16.10 and reinstall” keep my Win7 installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885711/will-erase-ubuntu16-10-and-reinstall-keep-my-win7-installation)

Comment: Thanks,I will look into that.

Comment: Thanks guiverc and karel, I finally got my computer working again and it worked the way it was suggested, a total new installation. Ton