# How to create a bootable usb stick for ubuntu on RHEL 6

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb, system-installation

I want to create a bootable usb stick for installing ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. Currently I have access to an RHEL 6 machine.

Ubuntu has [guides for installing from usb stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick), and two methods mentioned are: 1. Unetbootin and 2. mksub. I tried to install unetbootin on RHEL 6, which failed with the error `Error: Package: unetbootin-0-15.585bzr.el6.x86_64 (epel) Requires: syslinux-extlinux`. Also, `yum search mksub` returned nothing (as well as my Google search didn't return anything useful).

I was wondering if anyone has experience in creating Ubuntu installer stick from RHEL 6. Thanks.

Comment: Youn should ask this on a forum related to Fedora. Fedora is a compeletly different system so it will have a specific answer we are not supposed to know ;) http://unix.stackexchange.com/ is the place to ask this. In Ubuntu the easiest method is: dash->usb startup.

Comment: You can make a live flash drive with dd. Asking about making an ubuntu live cd on a fedora forums is going to go about as good as asking how to make a fedora live usb here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my suggestion:

1. isoinfo -d -i foobar.iso (get the Volume Size and Block Size)
2. dd if=foobar.iso bs=2048 count=344064 of=/dev/sda   (or whatever the usb path is)

The bs and count is probably optional, but it's better to be safe.  If you do a search, you'll find similar posts and solutions.  Here's another example solution.

[How to burn a Windows .iso to a USB device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59551/how-to-burn-a-iso-to-a-usb-device)