# Extracting a strange .zip

Tags: sd-card, transmission, zip, raspberrypi

I just downloaded the Raspberry Pi (rate) image from [the PirateBox webpage.](http://piratebox.cc/raspberry_pi:diy) I received a zip file containing only one file, called raw_arch_image (no extension).

The zip itself is called `ArchLinuxARMv6-2015-06_PirateBox1.0.2_rpi_1.0.5.img.zip`
There is apparently supposed to be a disk image somewhere in this, how do I write it to an SD card?

[image]

Comment: http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup#Flashing_the_SD_Card_using_Linux_.28including_on_a_Pi.21.29 And are you using ubuntu? or windows?

Comment: @Tim Ubuntu, what did you think? the main issue is that the .zip is being weird.

Comment: Can you not extract the zip? It has the extension..?

Comment: @Tim When i extract the zip, I get a file named raw_arch_image. This file is not a disk image, and opens in and freezes notepad. it almost seems like you didn't read the whole question.

Comment: I'm not telling you to open it in notepad, and i did read the question. How do you know it's not a disk image?

Comment: @Tim [here's the folder with the zip.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sztqg6s9rxz7e38/Screenshot%20from%202015-06-26%2010%3A29%3A27.png?dl=0)

Comment: Right click, extract here?

Comment: @magi093 that probably is the image? However, I have had similar issues with file roller. Try opening it, and not extracting it with file roller, to see whats inside the zip file? if it has a different name, drag and drop that file in to your folder. Another thing you could try, is using unzip. "unzip BLAH.zip", should unzip the file.

Comment: @Tim How do you think that raw_arch_image_file got there?

Comment: @blade19899 been there done that got the raw_arch_image_file.

Comment: right okay... so your issue wasn't extracting. anyway, how do you know that isn't the disk image? I think it is

Comment: @Tim [THIS](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s9t2gdf4ofqtnje/Screenshot%20from%202015-06-26%2010%3A48%3A25.png?dl=0)

Comment: That. Is. The. Image. http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup#Using_the_Linux_command_line I undid the edit because you have extracted it, and the issue is not the zip file.

Comment: @Tim Here goes nothing...

Comment: @magi093 it is image. just change the extension to `.img` as zip name says... there is nothing strange about it. And meaning of `raw_name_image` is: `A Raw Disk Image contains an exact, sector-by-sector copy of a single partition or disk. The .img filename extension is used by disk image files, which contain raw dumps of a magnetic disk or of an optical disc`

Comment: Also http://elinux.org provide a "How to" make bootable SD... and if you can`t figure out how... And why the hell would you open Image in notepad? I would start with something easier, if I were you ;)

Comment: @MiHa the notepad was just me double clicking the file like the noob that I am. :P

Comment: @magi093 any `ISO mounter` should be able to mount the file, even if it has not an extension :). About burning it to USB/SD: http://askubuntu.com/questions/59551/how-to-burn-a-iso-to-a-usb-device (it is applicable to Linux and .img format as well) - on 99% this thread should be enough

Answer (score 0):

The file without an extension inside your zip file *is* the image file. It just has no extension.

I assure you it has extracted correctly.