# Ubuntu.iso - how to use it?

Tags: chromebook

So, I have chromebook (Samsung 503c), and I was turn on the developer mode, and turn on usb boot, so I download a `ubuntu.iso` file, but I can't extract it to my usb stick.

How I can do that (extract to usb Ubuntu files)?

Comment: NO, I cant open any .exe files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that your iso is at /home/user/abc/ubuntu.iso

to move the iso to a usb drive do the following:

1. Get a shell on your chromebook by hitting `ctrl+alt+T`
2. Type `shell` and press enter to get a proper shell instead of *crosh*
3. insert your USB thumbdrive, and type `dmesg|tail` to see what it is registered as (mine is sdb1)
4. Make sure that the drive is not mounted by typing `sudo umount /dev/sdb1`
5. Copy the iso to the disk by typing `sudo dd bs=4M if=/home/user/abc/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdb`

Wait for it to finish. and now you should have a working usb disk with ubuntu iso on it, ready to boot.

Comment: Oh no, I don't want install with crouton, because its piece of shit

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/59551/how-to-burn-a-iso-to-a-usb-device) article covers the dd command;
sudo umount /dev/sd[1 letter][optionally 1 number]

sudo dd bs=4M if=[path_to_your.iso] of=/dev/sd[that 1 letter]

Comment: Jonas - please give me example, becauso, it's not workig :D

Comment: I've rewritten my answer to address your comments

Comment: @Pain You've also got me thinking about installing Linux on my chromebook now

Comment: Since this post, I have installed XUbuntu on my own chromebook, using similar approach to this, with great success. If you require a machine that works well , disconnected from the interweb, i warmly reccomend it.