# Upgrading to windows 10

Tags: windows

hi so I bought windows 10 and I’m using Ubuntu, and i want to just use windows now and get rid of Ubuntu. I have no clue how to do this or how I can even start, I have the .iso file and I’m ready to start, but like how? I cant just open it, it says I cant, please help asap. keep in mind I’m really bad at the whole Linux thing so please try and clearly go through step by step as if I’m completely new, because I really am, thank-you :) I've tried googling it and i dont understand it at all, i was hoping someone can walk me through it really easy and simple :) also my cd drive doesnt work...

Comment: from what i understand thats with a cd, i cant use/have the cd, i only have the .iso file

Comment: @j.stacey the answer on that question also describes what to do if you only have the ISO file.

Comment: i think im really stupid, i cant see where, and i followed the steps and it didnt help at all

Comment: For that, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/59551/how-to-burn-a-windows-iso-to-a-usb-device

Answer (score 0):

burn the iso to a dvd with brasero or k3b much as you would on windows . once its complete restart your computer into the boot menu and boot it from your dvd drive and at that point you should be ready to install

Comment: can i do it anyway with a usb? as my cd drive isnt working...

Answer (score 0):

Use Unetbootin in Linux or Rufus in windows to make installation usb for windows and then treat it like a CD. Set bios to boot from usb.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the ISO file on your computer. You can put ISO on a DVD or an USB key and then boot from DVD or USB and install windows.

1. For DVD right click on ISO file and select "Open with Disc Burner" and burn the ISO file to your DVD. Then boot the computer from DVD (https://www.google.com/?q=how+to+boot+from+DVD) and install Windows (https://www.google.com/?q=Install+windows+10).
2. For USB right click on ISO file and select "Open With" -> "Disk Image Writer". Write the ISO file to an USB key and boot from USB (https://www.google.com/?q=how+to+boot+from+USB) and install Windows (https://www.google.com/?q=Install+windows+10).