# How do I reset my PC?

Tags: windows

This new PC that I have was gifted to me, and I am brand new to Ubuntu, and I would rather use windows because it is something that I am used to because I use it for school 24/7. I have been trying to follow along with tutorials on youtube,but whenever there is a certain command, it says that the file isn't there, and I don't know if I have a dual boot computer or not. And the terminal commands that I have tried are either incredibly long or result in an endless void of language that I don't understand. If there is a simpler way to remove my computer of Ubuntu and replace it with Windows 10, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I have looked at the above suggested link, and to me it seems one needs to obtain a Windows installer media. I guess that would involve [downloading it](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) from the Microsoft website. But what nobody seems to talk about is how does one put it on a bootable USB drive, when the only available OS to do it is Ubuntu.

Comment: While of course you can always replace Ubuntu with Windows, I would like to ask **what do you exactly want to do** with your computer that you know how to do in Windows, and don't know how to do in Ubuntu? Just trying random commands isn't the best idea. Please state your goal (ie. what do you want to do with the computer) and maybe someone will be able to help you to do that in Ubuntu.

Comment: @Levente see [How to burn a Windows ISO to a USB device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59551/how-to-burn-a-windows-iso-to-a-usb-device). This question has been answered multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to make a bootable pendrive (https://www.balena.io/etcher/) with a windows iso file. Plug it in, restart the computer, get into the BIOS, change the boot order to the pendrive, save and exit. After that the computer should restart and the windows installer will shows up.