# Any way to manually make a bootable USB from ISO?

Tags: boot, iso, unetbootin

I've been using Unetbootin but it occasionally fails to create a bootable usb the way I need it to, especially with the newer versions.

Is there a way I could extract the iso myself?

Comment: Extracting the ISO will not make a Bootable USB/CD/DVD

Comment: Here is how to extract ISO to usb and make it boot able
http://askubuntu.com/a/116886/35775

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned by the OP. Voting to close it.

Answer (score 26):

This is a bit destructive, but works all the time. It will write everything to the /dev/sdb (which is the usb device. )

```
sudo dd if=/path/to.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=16M
```

read the manpage of dd

Comment: This will only work if it is a hybrid ISO containing an MBR and partitioning to allow you to use it as a disk image too.  So it may or may not work for the questioner's case.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge: This is true, however, most "live CD" ISOs have this property. So, this method should work for most real-live use-cases.

Comment: `isohybrid` is a useful command for this purpose: http://superuser.com/a/592656/45927

Comment: @EhteshChoudhury that is how the kernel does it on `make isoimage`: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/64291f7db5bd8150a74ad2036f1037e6a0428df2/arch/x86/boot/Makefile#L177

Comment: worked fine on my laptop when booted in live cd with ubunto

Answer (score 1):

Depends. If you are going to use a Live Linux ISO like the Ubuntu LiveCDs then you can use the tool that comes with Ubuntu called **Startup Disk Creator**. Type `Startup` in Dash and it should appear there. From there on, the disk creator can create a Live USB from any Linux ISO that is a LiveCD.

If you are referring to a Windows ISO for example that changes everything. I suggest you see this question: [How to create a bootable USB from a .iso file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16277/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-from-a-iso-file)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this tutorial](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-make-a-bootable-usb-flash-drive-manually-859334/) it is possible.

Just use whatever distribution CD you choose in its place.

Note: Usually the failure to create a bootable USB is the USB itself. Some thumb drives just don't want to cooperate.

Comment: or a bad ISO...

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Answer (score -3):

Use the following Program:
Universal USB Installer [Click Here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com)

Comment: That's not manually.

Comment: @techtonik It's as "manual" as dd or any other piece of software that performs the same function.

Comment: @JasonC, are you sure that simple raw copy from ISO to USB is enough to make it bootable? I thought that you need to do some checks that ISO fits USB correctly and set some bits to make it bootable.